# How to start/stop ActiveJob workers in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, production-environment, worker, rails-activejob

I'm using ActiveJob in development (with delayed_job as a queuing backend but I think that is irrelevant) to do things like sending emails asynchronously or logging some events.

In development, in a terminal, I execute `rake jobs:work` to start the worker process, I use `CTRL+C` to kill it, and I use `rake jobs:clear` to empty the queue.

How do I do this in production (a droplet on DigitalOcean) and how do I know that my worker is running even though I'm not logged in on the server? I usually deploy with [mina](https://github.com/mina-deploy/mina), can I script that in my `deploy.rb`?

Comment: There's no such thing as ActiveJob worker. It's just an interface. Actual workers will be DJ or sidekiq or whathaveyou. So, depending on what you actually use, you need to take specific steps to deploying/monitoring it. Cursory googling reveals this example script: https://gist.github.com/stas/4539489

Comment: Isn't ActiveJob an interface on the underlying backend? Whether I use Resque or Sidekiq, I can start the worker locally with `rake jobs:work`. I'm looking at how to do the same in production (and how to know it's running as well as emptying the queue).

Comment: Are you sure about `rake jobs:work`? As far as I know, this one comes from DJ, not active job. Could you point me to documentation?

Comment: Actually, you are correct. I thought this was the way to start any backend queue engine. It only applies to DJ. Which makes things a little bit clearer for me.